# How can I test my Game Maker Studio 2 project on an android virtual device?

Tags: android, android-studio, game-maker-studio-2

I have been trying unsuccessfully for a few days now to test my game on a virtual android device.  I used the following article to set it up:
https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001368727-Setting-Up-For-Android

Because it did not work the first time, I decided to try uninstalling Android Studio using the guide found here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-windows/

One thing I noted is that when I follow this guide, I get the following message:
[image: image of popup window]

After clicking yes, I then go through the rest of the uninstall guide uneventfully.

From here, I retry the yoyogames article about setting up for android.  When I get to the SDK components setup, I notice that I do not have as many options as they do in the article.  Here is what I have:
[image: picture of window]

I am unable to check the middle button as well, which says, "Android SDK Platform".  I set the path to C:/AndroidSDK like in the article.

After this, I went into the SDK manager and installed the most recent one, Android SDK Platform 31.  Then I installed the corresponding SDK build-tools, and ndk 21.4.7075529.

I skipped the amazon fire section, and the went through the game maker studio preferences setup, pointing game maker to the sdk, ndk, and jdk.  I created a keystore as well, saved to a file on my desktop.  Then, I used this article:

https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000270191-Android-Setting-Up-Virtual-Devices

to set up virtual devices using the avd.  I ran the new virtual device, a Pixel 5 API 30, and connected to it from game maker.  I left the android game options as there defaults, seen here:
[image: game options]

When I run the game, the only output I get is `Build Failed`.
I can provide more info upon request, any help would be very greatly appreciated.  I have no idea what is happening.

Update:
Here is some additional error output from the output tab:

````
Execution failed for task ':com.company.game:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s


C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe DONE (1)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\subst.exe /d W:


C:\WINDOWS\system32\subst.exe DONE (0)
Error : Build Failed
Igor complete.```
````

Comment: I see you're using android studio... When running the app, there is a build item you can click to see more information about why it failed..

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 Alright... is this in android studio or gms2?  And how exactly do I find it?

Comment: In android studio, on the items at the bottom, there is one saying build... When you build, there you can see what succeeded and what failed. Also there is an item for logs, there is some information there too.

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 I see... I checked here and I do not have any build problems.  I do have several lines of red text on the Logcat though.  Like in the article above, I am only using android studio to get the sdk/ndk/jdk and to run the emulator... I am not importing a project into Android studio, the article seems to suggest I can run the test directly from GMS2.

Comment: Well, try importing the project. It is easy and may be better.

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 I could possibly try this, although there is nothing in any of the articles that mentions importing to android studio to test, and I am not at all familiar with android studio, and am only using it to fulfill gms2's requirements...

Comment: For anyone seeing this in the future, the issue was that I had a much newer version of Android studio than GMS2 supports.  I went back and installed Android Studio 4.2.0 from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive , and it worked just fine on that.